# Django Json data as string

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I have a project where I have to get JSON data from one API endpoint and then pull some data from this JSON data and send it to another API.

From first API I am getting this data:

```
response ={  
   "abc":"AP003",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "d":{  
            "e":"some data",
            "f":"some data"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I extract data from this and send it to another view.

```
response = response.json()
response = response['data']
return JsonResponse(json.dumps(response),safe=False)
```

Even below code does not work

```
response = response.json()
response = response['data']
return JsonResponse(response,safe=False)
```

When I do this I get response but data I get is in string form and not in JSON form.
How to get JSON data and send it to template as it is?

Edit:

> I have a JSON in a string format and I want it to send as JSON form in
>   my API response

Comment: just pass response, no need to use json dumps

Comment: If I do that then I am getting '"/data/":/[  
      {  /
         "/d/":/{  
            "e":"some data",
            "f":"some data"
         }
      }
   ]'

Comment: @BugHunter Getting `/` after every word.

Comment: You have to use data.json() .

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool It gives error. I have edited question to avoid confusion.

Comment: when you are getting response of API on UI and then in you front end code you have to use `response.json();`  like `res = response.json();` and then `res` will have response without `/` etc.

Comment: if you are getting this response data in another API in PYTHON then use `json.loads(response)` or `json.loads(request.body)`

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Data I get from another API has no issue. I am able to use it. I have to just pull some data from it and send it to httpresponse or jsonresponse. But when I take that part and send it, its going as string and no json.

Comment: where are you getting that 2nd response  ?  on front end side ?

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Yes front end side.

Comment: please show your front end code where you are getting that response.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool There is no front end code. Its a jsonresponse

Comment: oh ho!,  in API you are sending json response `return JsonResponse(response,safe=False)` and then where you are getting this 2nd response ?

Comment: You are using POSTMAN type tool to hit API ?

Comment: No, Django requests

Comment: then again use `response.json( )` to get json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have response dict as follows, then there is no need to perform extra operations. you can directly pass that to JsonResponse, which will be converted to json.

```
response ={  
   "abc":"AP003",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "d":{  
            "e":"some data",
            "f":"some data"
         }
      }
   ]
}

return JsonResponse({"data": response['data']})
```